# Output (echo?) direct children of parent custom taxonomy in a loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, parent-child, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to output only 1st child level (not parent or grandchildren) custom taxonomies in a loop of some sort, so i can add custom fields / thumbnails to it.

I created a hierarchical custom post type called 'product-type'

And there are a few levels of custom taxonomies to it.

Level 1 - Snacks

Level 2 - Chocolates (just showing 1 for this example)

Level 3 - Milk Chocolates, Dark Chocolates ..and so on.

on the parent taxonomy page, i've been able to successfully list all the existing Level 2 taxonomies with the following code:

```
<?php 
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); 
if ($term->parent == 0) {  
wp_list_categories('taxonomy=product-type&depth=1&show_count=0
&title_li=&child_of=' . $term->term_id);
} else {
wp_list_categories('taxonomy=product-type&show_count=0
&title_li=&child_of=' . $term->parent); 
}
?>
```

the output looks something like this:

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-7">
<a href="..." title="...">Chocolates</a> (14)
</li>
```

My question is, how do i edit the php code above such that i can output (echo?) only only 1st child level (not parent or grandchildren) taxonomy in some sort of a loop where i can insert divs or with custom fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on for size.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

```
<?php 
$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); 
if ($term->parent == 0) {  
    $terms = get_terms( 'product-type', 'child_of='.$term->term_id );
} else {
    $terms = get_terms( 'product-type', 'child_of='.$term->parent );
}
foreach($terms as $term) {
    // Your custom HTML
}
?>
```

Comment: heres what i did   `$term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) ); 
if ($term->parent == 0) {  
    $terms = get_terms( 'product-type', 'child_of='.$term->term_id );
} else {
    $terms = get_terms( 'product-type', 'child_of='.$term->parent );
}
foreach($terms as $term) {
 echo '<div><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></div>';
}`

it works but its showing child taxonomies for level 2 AND 3. how do i show only level 2?

Comment: Looking at the codex documentation, here is what is says about the **child_of** parameter. `Note: the difference between child_of and parent is that where parent only gets direct children of the parent term (ie: 1 level down), child_of gets all descendants (as many levels as are available)`. So just change **child_of** to **parent** for both **get_terms** calls and you should be good.

Comment: fantastic! works! 
was racking my brain the whole day trying to fix this